# Odd limitation in editing

Tags: support, editing

I have just tried to make a fairly obvious edit to a question:

I tried to replace the word "aloud" with "allowed".

It seems totally obvious that "allowed" is correct in this context, but the software tells me that my edit is unacceptable since I have only changed 6 characters ... and tells me that the minimum allowed (NOT "aloud"!!) is 10 characters.

What should I do, and what exactly am I aloud (allowed???) to do, in order to correct such a simple error in the light of these software limitations?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters

Comment: Thanks - would it be nice if the message I got when I tried to make the edit explained this? It would at least prevent multiple meta posts along the same lines.